# Codeigniter4 installation:you need to set your "document root" to the public folder inside your project

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am  trying to install codeigniter 4 on machine

I've downloaded the codeigniter4 from this repo https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4/tree/develop

From their documentation https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/index.html

> Open the application/Config/App.php file with a text editor and set
>   your base URL. If you intend to use encryption or sessions, set your
>   encryption key.

I've already done the above step but still i get this error message
f you see this message, you have not configured your web server properly.

```
You need to set your "document root" to the public folder inside your project. This could be your default setting, or that of a virtual host, depending on how you set up your local development environment.
```

**Directory structure**
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the files?

Comment: @Dray you mean directory sructure

Comment: Yes. And what are you using as your lamp stack?

Comment: I am using xampp with in windows

Comment: Did you make a folder in xampp/htdocs and put your codeigniter files in it? It should be like xampp/htdocs/project/(your CODEIGNITER extracted files)

Comment: Yes i am done that method

Comment: And you also set your base URL in config file? Can you also post what you  typed in base URL?

Comment: In app.php file   i am setting as base url as `public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/code4/';`

Comment: You need to run it from the public folder

Comment: sorry i didn't get it

Comment: Maybe this can explain you http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65910.html

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found the answer instead of running site from your project folder you should run it from public folder

`eg:localhost/codeigniter4/public` will give the page

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter4-develop\application\Config\App.php on line 293