# CSS, img, and favicon not loading in CodeIgniter 4, is it my htaccess?

Tags: css, image, .htaccess, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am very new to CodeIgniter and .htaccess protocols so bare with me. None of the assets in my assets folder are loading. Including the favicon. I have 3 errors when I inspect the home.php page but all of the file paths appear to be correct.

I fear the issue could lie in my .htaccess file at the root of my project. This is my directory structure:

```
App/
   Views/
      pages/
         home.php
public_html/
   .htaccess
   assets/
      css/
         light-theme.css
      img/
         shapes-background.jpg
   index.php
   favicon.ico
```

My controller App\Controllers\Home.php

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Home';

        echo view('templates/index_header', $data);
        echo view('pages/home');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if (! is_file(APPPATH . 'Views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

        echo view('templates/index_header', $data);
        echo view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|js|css|content|uploads|profile|favicon.ico|light-theme.css|)
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  ./index.php/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Allow phpmyadmin access
    RewriteCond $1 !^(phpmyadmin|index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Here is how I reference my css file:

```
<!-- Stylesheet file -->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?= base_url('assets/css/light-theme.css?version=51'); ?>' charset='utf-8'>
```

And here is how I reference an image to display:

```
<img src="<?= base_url(); ?>img/shapes-background.jpg" alt='Various Shapes'>
```

My baseurl is set inside App/Config/App.php:

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/Shape_Search/index.php/';
```

Comment: "*I have 3 errors when I inspect the home.php page*" - you forgot to mention what the errors are.  By "*inspect*" do you mean use your browser's devtools and look at the network tab?  That's a good place to diagnose this kind of problem if not.  You've shown the PHP you use to generate URLs etc, but how do those render in your HTML?

Comment: Yes, I meant inspect in my Firefox Developers browser. I get code 404 errors for the get css, img, and favicon requests? Does that help? I'll edit in my controller code.

Comment: Also, at one point my css and the favicon use to work but the img has never worked.

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are viewing when you see these errors?  Is it (eg) `http://localhost/Shape_Search/public_html/`? The `public_html` directory should be your web server's document root.  If it appears in your URLs - eg if you see `public_html` in your browser URL bar - it is not set up correctly.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39866904/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58719954/6089612, ...

Comment: This is my url for home.php ```http://localhost/home/view```

Comment: OK, so why does `$baseURL` look so different?

Comment: .htaccess îs all I can think of?

Comment: When I inspect the get requests, the url's point to the correct files. ```GET
 http://localhost/Shape_Search/public_html/assets/css/light-theme.css?version=51```

Comment: Why do you have `$baseURL` set up like you do?  What is the actual home page of your application, is that what you mean by `home.php` at `http://localhost/home/view`?  If so, why isn't **that** your `$baseURL`?  If you visit `http://localhost/home/view/assets/css/light-theme.css` does it work?

Comment: I downloaded the CodeIgniter 4 that has a beginners application pre-loaded. This is how I understood the ```$baseURL``` to be setup; pointing to the root where ```index.php``` resides. I think either the ```.htaccess``` or ```App\Config\Routes.php``` are the reason the URL displays as ```localhost/[controller]/[method]``` format.

Comment: I've tried all manner of ```$baseURL``` including ```http://localhost/``` and ```http://localhost/Shape_Search/``` but nothing changed.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so confused. MVC is new to me and I only barely grasp it so far.

Comment: try removing last RewriteCond  and RewriteRule , it has already been dealt with the earlier lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I have updated my ```.htaccess``` with my current file contents. Still same issue.

Comment: I removed the ```.htaccess``` file and no change. So it's not that.